# Unity: AudioSource becomes null (destroyed) when reloading current scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nullpointerexception

I am currently trying to reload the current scene after a game has ended.

In my Unity scene, I have an empty game object where I have multiple `AudioSource` game objects:

[image]

And then I have another game object called `AudioService` which has the script `AudioService.cs` which has references to these `AudioService`. Nothing really unusual:

[image]

Everything works when I start the game / scene.

However, after I reload the current scene with:

```
Debug.Log("[SceneUtil] ReloadCurrentScene");
SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
```

Everything seems to have been reloaded, but the Audio breaks after a while.

In `AudioService.Start` I see that the Audio Sources do have references:

```
void Start() {
        Debug.Log("[AudioService] [Start] Started");
        Debug.Log("[AudioService] [Start] audioSourceMusic=" + this.audioSourceMusic);
}
```

[image]

So, so far so good.

But later on in the game (after I have loaded in all my settings), the references becomes null:

```
    public void onSettingsLoaded()
    {
        Debug.Log("[AudioService] [onSettingsLoaded] audioSourceMusic=" + this.audioSourceMusic);
        this.audioSourceMusic.volume = SettingsService.settings.soundVolumeMusic;
        this.audioSourceSFX.volume = SettingsService.settings.soundVolumeSFX;
    }
```

How come the reference becomes lost from `Start` to later on in the execution when reloading the Scene?

Is there anyway I can troubleshoot what's going on?

[image]

Comment: How does `onSettingsLoaded` get called? Are these service objects marked as DontDestroyOnLoad?

Comment: I haven't used "DontDestroyOnLoad" at all, and `onSettingsLoaded` is just an observer pattern, when a .json file is read in by the init-scripts. I don't think those are related, but I cannot figure out why the reference becomes `null` after a Scene reload.

Comment: Please clarify the observer pattern, probably the observer keeps observing the old `AudioService`.

Comment: The observer pattern are `static` class methods, so it is very possible that these do not get destroyed/unloaded? I am not entirely sure how unload/destroy works in Unity. Maybe static class fields does not get

Comment: Static fields do not get destroyed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comments it sounds like `onSettingsLoaded` is attached as listener to an event/observable that is `static`

=> When this object is being unloaded/destroyed due to your scene reloading you forgot to remove the listener

=> The moment the event/observable is invoked you still trigger the attachd listener which belongs to an "invalid" instance which's underlying `GameObject` has been destroyed already - and so have all the other referenced objects such as your `AudioSource`s

---

Always make sure to unsubscribe listeners once they are not required anymore.

I don't see how exactly you attach the listener but regarding simple `event` it might look like e.g.

```
private void Awake()
{
    YourObservedClass.someEvent += Listener;
}

private void OnDestroy()
{
    YourObservedClass.someEvent -= Listener;
}

private void Listener()
{
    ...
}
```

this way it is assured that the `Listener` will not be called anymore after the object has been destroyed